# Saving captured image as apattern file?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Can i save captured image from Camera as (.pat) pattern file ?

if i can't , is there any third party library can help me in that in windows phone or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, this is a proprietary file format owned by Adobe. Take a look at this post: http://www.selapa.net/swatches/patterns/fileformats.php for more information. Maybe you can write your own file writer.

Why can't you perform the conversion in Photoshop?

Comment: i need this programatical to capture image then save it as(pat) file so , i can not use Photoshop

Comment: Well, unless you will write your own file writer, you need to find one. Why do you need exactly that file format?

Comment: for augmented reality purposes this format is needed to match with camera shots.